# What's the meaning of "other hours"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, ambiguity, phrase-meaning

I'm stuck with the phrase "other hours" used in the following context:

> Hours went into the plotting of graphs, and **other hours** into instructing an assistant how to plot.

Does that mean that 1/2 of time (one part) was dedicated to plotting, and 1/2 of time (the other part) went into instructing? I get it like there were two equal parts, but would appreciate if English speakers share their opinions.

Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't necessarily imply that there are two equal parts. Instead, it just states that hours went into plotting and hours went until instructing. It's vague in the sense that the number of hours are unknown. It could be 50/50 but it also could be 20/80

Comment: It's suggesting that he spent a significant amount of time on each activity, but they didn't overlap. "other" just means that they're different sets of hours.

Comment: The sentence emphasizes that the hours were long, that's all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does not say that the two times were equal.  It does not say how long the times were, other than that they were long enough to be counted in hours.  It only says that:

- Some hours were spend plotting graphs.
- Some hours were spent instructing an assistant.
- The hours spend plotting graphs were not the same hours as the ones spent instructing the assistant, that is why they are referred to as "other hours".